# Having Full-screen website with slide up blog page

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, slider

I am working on this new site and am having difficulties implementing this one functionality. The link is:

www.bigideaadv.com/adaptive2

I am using the Supersized.js plugin to make the image fit the size of the browser no matter the size or shape. I have also implemented a Wordpress blog as well under news+events. What I'd like to do is have the blog slide up from the bottom when you click on the link and back down when you click on another page. Exactly how the blog link works here:

www.ultranoir.com

I originally had all of the content shoved in the header.php file in Wordpress and was doing show hides. Needless to say, I was unsuccessful. Wondering if anyone had an thoughts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you own the other website? If not I would be very careful, you are very close to plagiarising the design.

Comment: You may want to change the wording of this question as it is unclear what exactly you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into Wordpress Theming. It's pretty straight forward and there is a lot of great documentation found here: 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

You wouldn't want to put all the code into the `header.php` file because that's not how wordpress works. You'll want to edit other files such as `single.php` and `index.php`.

Though for the "slide up / down" you should be able to use some simple jQuery for this:

```
$('#yourSlideMenuButton').slideToggle("slow", function(){
    //do something when finished. 
});
```

Please be careful not to plagiarize the other design!